# Intuitions on Kumaresan-Tufts algorithm for exponential fit

Tags: matlab, decomposition, linear-prediction

I am analyzing a transient signal presumably consisting of superposed exponentials. Such a case is indicated for the Prony analysis, but my data aren't noiseless enough, so I have turned to the Kumaresan-Tufts (KT) algorithm.

After reading the original article ([Estimating the Parameters of Exponentially Damped Sinusoids and Pole-Zero Modeling in Noise](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/data/sonar/KumaresanTufts.pdf), 1982) and a bit of googling I made use of the [Matlab package Complex Exponential Analysis](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12439-complex-exponential-analysis) and more or less things work

My concern is now an intuition on the process - or, better, on its input parameters (cause FFT-like thinking is of course out of question):

- What should I expect of increasing or decreasing of model order?
- How can I assess the number of modes decinig for signal reconstruction and how can I pick them from the output parameters (dampings, frequencies, complex amplitudes)?
- Is there any recommended signal treatment before the KT method is applied? Such as detrending the data for FFT.
- Does time-inverting of the signal providing any help? It would mean damped exponentials instead of growing.

Comment: Several years ago I did research on a different (or at least more current) approach to exponential curve/function fitting/modeling.  Although I didn't actually implement it I did see my way clear to using it.   I can give some references and after some thought (to make sure my memory is refreshed) some ideas about how it can be used; but it's basically using a specialized form of orthogonal polynomials and decreasing the residual PSD with exponentials as the basis functions.  The search term would be Muntz polynomials.

Comment: Sorry if my last posting seemed off topic but  I do think my analysis approach clarifies the questions asked.  Even though they were about a different algorithm.  The Muntz approach is a lot more signal oriented than others I have seen.  Personally, I managed to get Prony to work most of the time.

Comment: @rrogers, is there an outline of your approach on the web ?
Any comments on the methods in
[12439-complex-exponential-analysis](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12439-complex-exponential-analysis?) ? Thanks

Comment: I will look at the link.  My proposed method is simple: There is an orthogonal set of basis functions for any choice of exponential $a*exp(b*x)$ parameters.  We successively choose new basis functions with parameters a_x,b_x so that the new orthogonal vector minimizes the squared values of the previous residuals.  The idea is that the optimization is done against the power/square of the new residuals.  So the successive residuals are always diminished.  The reason for this criterion is that I have run system identification optimization where extra terms did not converge.  Which is silly.